# How do I use a multi-character delimiter for array expansion in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo, printf

I'm reducing the question to (I believe) the simplest case.  Let's say I have a script `myscript.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='%20'
echo "$*"
```

If I run the command as follows, the output will look like:

```
me@myhost ~ $ ./myscript.sh fee fi fo fum
fee%fi%fo%fum
```

This is expected behavior, as described in the `bash` man page:

```
   *      Expands  to  the positional parameters, starting from one.  When
          the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a  sin-
          gle word with the value of each parameter separated by the first
          character of the IFS special variable.  That is, "$*" is equiva-
          lent to "$1c$2c...", where c is the first character of the value
          of the IFS variable.  If IFS is unset, the parameters are  sepa-
          rated  by  spaces.   If  IFS  is null, the parameters are joined
          without intervening separators.
```

However, what I would like to get is the output:

```
fee%20fi%20fo%20fum
```

Thus using a multiple character separator field rather than a single character.

Is there a way to do this that is native to `bash`?

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the data from mikeserv below, and the writeup at [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), I ended up doing the following (again reduced to simplest case as in the example above):

```
#!/bin/bash
word="$1"
shift
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ] ; then
    word="$word$(printf '%%20%s' "$@")"
fi
printf '%s\n' "$word"
unset word
```

Comment: there is `printf %s%%20 "$@"` but that will do an extra one on the tail of the output. if you can be sure none of the args might be misinterpreted there is `printf %b%%20 "$@\c"`. else you can do: `for arg do shift; set -- "$@" %20 "$arg"; done; shift; printf %s "$@"`

Comment: That's perfect!  Add it as an answer with an explanation of the bits and pieces and I'll accept it.  One more reason I need to learn `printf` and stop leaning on `echo`....

Comment: `word=$1${2+$(shift;printf %%20%s "$@")}` - and you don't even have to lose `$1` because it only gets shifted in the subshell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` applies its format string to each argument that follows it on output. It is a `bash` shell builtin and can be used to apply a delimiter string to a list of arguments - kind of.

For example:

```
printf %s:delimit: arg1 arg2 arg3
```

---

```
arg1:delimit:arg2:delimit:arg3:delimit:
```

The thing is, `printf` doesn't *stop* applying its format string at the end of its arguments, and so the last one gets an appended delimiter. This can be handled in some cases:

```
printf %b:delimit: \\0150 \\0145 \\0171\\c
```

---

```
h:delimit:e:delimit:y
```

`printf` interprets C and octal escapes as `%b`ytes with a certain kind of format, and also with the `%b` format you `\c`ut its output at a certain point, which is why `printf` does not follow the y above with a `:delimit:` string as its format string would otherwise indicate.

So if you want every argument literally interpreted *and* no trailing delimiter, then you have to address the problem within the argument list itself:

```
set -- arg1 arg2 arg3
for arg do shift
    set -- "$@" :delimit: "$arg"
done; shift
printf %s "$@"
```

---

```
arg1:delimit:arg2:delimit:arg3
```

Comment: Perfect!  I also found http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`, you can use `j:string:` [Parameters Expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-parameter-expansion-flags):

```
set -- fee fi fo fum
delims=%20
print -rl ${(j:$delims:)@}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `bash` (or other shell with variable expansion enabled) and arguments do not have spaces inside you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$*
echo "${line// /:delimiter:}"
```

In the case of spaces you will have to use other field delimiter by setting `IFS` variable before `line`.